# Android Studio App crashes when i press the submit button to go to a 2nd activity

Tags: java, android

Firstly, I am pretty new to Android programming and I am trying to develop a simple app that shows a message, and when you press the button that's under the message, it sends you to a 2nd activity, which is a form. The app isn't linked to any database, I was just trying to develop a validation algorithm within the app, so the data that's written in the EditText's it's correct. Like the Name only with letters, etc. I created both activities, it worked to jump from the 1st one to the 2nd one after pressing the button, but that was before I added the validation algorithm. Now, with that implemented, whenever I press on the "Start!" button(1st activity-submit one), the apps just crashes.

**The manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity
            android:name=".Inregistrare"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme1" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**The 1st app `MainActivity.java`:**

```
 package com.example.myapplication;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Inregistrare();
            }
            });
            }
            public void Inregistrare(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Inregistrare.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
```

**The 2nd activity `Inregistrare.java`:**

```
   package com.example.myapplication;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    public class Inregistrare extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText nume, prenume, email, telefon;
        TextView rezultat;
        Button submit;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_inregistrare);
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                { final   String Nume = nume.getText().toString();
                    final String Prenume=prenume.getText().toString();
                    final String Email=email.getText().toString();
                    final String Telefon=telefon.getText().toString();
                if(Nume.length()==0)
                {
                    nume.requestFocus();
                    nume.setError("Campul nu poate fi lasat liber");
                }
                else if(!Nume.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+"))
                {
                    nume.requestFocus();
                    nume.setError("Campul poate fi completat doar cu litere");
                }
                else if(Prenume.length()==0)
                {
                    prenume.requestFocus();
                    prenume.setError("Campul nu poate fi lasat liber");
                }
                else if(!Prenume.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                    prenume.requestFocus();
                    prenume.setError("Campul poate fi completat doar cu litere");
                }
                else if(Email.length()==0)
                {
                    email.requestFocus();
                    email.setError("Campul nu poate fi lasat liber");
                }
                else if(!Email.matches("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$"))
                {
                    email.requestFocus();
                    email.setError("Campul poate fi completat doar cu litere");
                }
                else if(Telefon.length()==0 || Telefon.length()<10)
                {
                    telefon.requestFocus();
                    telefon.setError("Campul nu poate fi lasat liber si trebuie sa aiba minim 10 cifre");
                }
                else if(!Telefon.matches("[0-9]+"))
                {
                    telefon.requestFocus();
                    telefon.setError("Campul poate fi completat doar cu cifre");
                }
                else{
                    rezultat = findViewById(R.id.rezultat);
                    String date="Date corecte!";
                    rezultat.setText(date);
                }
            }
        })
        ;}
    }
```

I tried using another activity to check the switch and it works. The problem is somewhere in `inregistrare.java` (2nd activity) but i cant seem to find it. I didnt add the .xml's because i dont this that there's any problem. As i said i am pretty new to this, so please be kind and dont yell at me if i did a big mistake.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you put the crash log ?

Comment: Can you provide crash logs

Comment: You never initialize `submit` in `onCreate` in 2nd activity.

Comment: Andy's answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks Andy! That was the issue indeed. The other problem now it is that when I complete the fields, after I press the submit button on the 2nd activity, the app firstly comes back on the 1st activity, and if I try again it crashes. I cannot add the crash logs due to character limit

Comment: @costlin You can paste crash log somewhere and add link to it in your question.

Comment: @xaif Thanks! I rechecked the code and when I tried to debugg the 1st issue, I accidentely deleted some variable initializations. It works now, thanks!